# PHP mysql: registration returning false

Tags: php, mysql, forms, registration

I am trying to enter values in the database from two textboxes yet when I submit the username and password i get this error:  user has not been entered on the database check with administrator of the system.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $logged_in = isset($_SESSION['USERNAME']) && $_SESSION['USERNAME'] ?
 $_SESSION['USERNAME'] : null;
    if(!$logged_in) {   
    }
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
include 'dbconfig.php';

     global $db;


$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

// encrypting password
$encrypted_password=md5($password);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($username)); 
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



if (! $row){

//add new user to database
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user_info(username, password) VALUES (?,?)");
$params1 = array($username, $encrypted_password);



if (!$stmt ->execute($params1)){
echo "user has not been entered on the database check with administrator of the system.  
<span class='label label-important'>Important</span>";

}else{
echo $username." has been added to the database as a supervisor. <span class='label 
label-success'>Success</span>";


}
else{
echo $username." is already a user of the system <span class='label label- 
warning'>Warning</span>";

}
$db = null; 
?>
```

var_dump($row); returns a false boolean and it will not load the values into the database.
Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: What is size of your username and password field in table? Have you properly checked the size of username/password length against the table field length at the time of user input?

Comment: I haven't performed any checks I wasn't aware I had to do this?

Comment: You have a space here after `!$stmt`
`if (!$stmt ->execute($params1))`

Was this just a typo?

Comment: No, thi was in my code, I have amended this but it doesn't change the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it is not fully understandable where is the error.

But,

as you get error in

```
if (!$stmt ->execute($params1)){
```

statement, I assume that it is a database related error.

So first check what is the size of username field in the table. make a maxlength checking in user input against the field.

Also, to note, a md5 password encryption returns near 30 characters. So it is safe to make your password field 50 char long.

Also there may be other causes for the error, but please confirm those above first and try it again.

Thanks

Comment: Oh it's the most simple error username should have been user_id in the INSERT INTO statement, can't believe that I made that error...thanks for bringing it to my attention that it was a database error.